# How to move Up and Down one widget according to button click in Flutter?

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new bee for Flutter. I have one line widget in screen.
I have 2 button "+" and "-".
When I click on "+", line widget should comes Down.
When I click on "-", line widget should comes Up.

How to achieve that?

Thanks In Advance.
Please Help.

Comment: Maybe you can try putting your widgets in a List, and then modify that list with functions.

Comment: No, I just up and down means line widget moves in Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that is using [AnimatedContainer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) .

Wrap your line in and AnimatedContainer and change `alignment` property when hit the button.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the widgets in a "List" , then reorder it , base on action (click, drag, ... ) , if you can provide us with your current code (example that can run it in the main directly) , it well be more helpful